# Possible flaw in Builder pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, builder-pattern

Could someone explain, why do we need to have getResult() method? Why buildPart() has no return value? It seems like an unnecessary step which has no real benefit. Why would we call buildPart() it we don't need the result?

I think it would be much more effective, if buildPart() returns the result.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Builder_UML_class_diagram.svg/500px-Builder_UML_class_diagram.svg.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The diagram you posted is unusual -- not a common Builder pattern -- and doesn't solve a common problem.  It doesn't make any sense without an explanation of what you're trying to achieve with it.